# Display the gridlines for y axis of bar-chart in achartengine android

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using the achartengine in my android application, so i don't know how to ***show the gridlines for the y axis in the bar-chart***. Does anyone know how to do with that?

[Bar chart grid lines for y axis image](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B3NUAgD0tB0YY1N3eDBDQjgyS1E)

Thanks for any helps

Clark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable all grid lines to be displayed by calling:

```
renderer.setShowGrid(true);
```

or you can enable them separately:

```
renderer.setShowGridX(true);
renderer.setShowGridY(true);
```

However, please note that grid lines are rendered along the chart labels.

Answer (score 1):

Answer given by Dan is correct.

You can enable by the below code.

```
 renderer.setShowGrid(true);
 renderer.setShowGridX(true);
 renderer.setShowGridY(true);`
```

You can disable the grid by below code

```
renderer.setShow(false);
renderer.setShowGridX(false);
renderer.setShowGridY(false);
```